# How to set up a server to allow the root user to track down historical outgoing requests?

Tags: ubuntu, logging, traffic

I woke up this morning and found an unexpected outgoing spike in traffic from my virtual server.
[image: Spike in outgoing traffic between 3 and 4 am]

What commands/settings should I have been using to allow myself to track down the who/what initiated these requests, what was being sent and where it was being sent to?

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
```

Comment: If you weren't already logging these information at that point (and if you were, you wouldn't need to ask now) the answer is most probably "none".

Comment: Noted. I'll updated my post accordingly

Comment: Apart from that, product recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Noted. I'll remove the request for tools and just leave a request of commands that would enable proper tracking.

Comment: auditd, acct or both come to mind